# Importing `IO` from scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

On `scala 2.11.6` and `scalaz 7.1.1`, I'm trying to get this [example](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/IO+Monad.html) working from [Learning scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz).

On the REPL, I can't import the necessary packages to call `IO.readLn`.

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._, effect._, IO._
<console>:7: error: not found: value effect
       import scalaz._, Scalaz._, effect._, IO._
                                  ^
<console>:7: error: not found: value IO
       import scalaz._, Scalaz._, effect._, IO._
```

Looking at [IO.scala](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/effect/src/main/scala/scalaz/effect/IO.scala), I don't see why I can't just `import scalaz.effect.IO`.

So, how can I properly import the package responsible for `IO`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scalaz-effect` is a separate artifact, and you're probably only depending on `scalaz-core`. You'll need to add this to `libraryDependencies` in your build configuration (assuming you're using SBT):

```
"org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-effect" % "7.1.1"
```

Just make sure the version matches the one for your `scalaz-core` dependency.

Comment: Yep, I had only included `scalaz-core`. Thanks, Travis.